# VBScript Redirect to Network Folder

Tags: vbscript, asp-classic

I have taken over a web page recently I have some programming knowledge and can usually muddle my way through things but I cant seem to get it today.

There is a snippet of code on the website that opens a folder on a network drive when a user opens one of the intranet pages. The folder is a location where all the users have a folder based on their network logins. I want it to open the users individual folder on the network drive based off their user name so the user doesnt have to search for their folder.

The current code I am using is the following and it opens the network drive with all user folders listed

```
<SCRIPT language=VBScript> 
sub SF1 
    window.location = "\\path to user folders\"
end sub 
id = SetTimeOut("SF1",0,"VBScript")
</SCRIPT>
```

The following code is what I would like but for some reason is not working

```
<SCRIPT language=VBScript> 
sub SF1 
    window.location = "\\path to user folders\" & username
end sub 
id = SetTimeOut("SF1",0,"VBScript")
</SCRIPT>
```

I am using the following to get the users login which is alwasy 6 characters long

```
Right(Request.ServerVariables("LOGON_USER"),6)
```

But when I try to use it like so nothing happens

```
<SCRIPT language=VBScript> 
sub SF1 
    window.location = "\\path to user folders\" & Right(Request.ServerVariables("LOGON_USER"),6)
end sub 
id = SetTimeOut("SF1",0,"VBScript")
</SCRIPT>
```

I have tried several permutations thinking it was an issue with the quotes maybe not being passed properly but I just can't figure it out any help would be appreciated.

Additionally if I type out the full path to a user folder it works just fine

```
<SCRIPT language=VBScript> 
sub SF1 
    window.location = "\\path to user folders\username\"
end sub 
id = SetTimeOut("SF1",0,"VBScript")
</SCRIPT>
```

Comment: I had tried it that way but it was the equal sign I was missing it now works. What does the equal sign change?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The `Request.ServerVariables` collection is available on the server side , you will have to get that value into the client side script :

```
window.location = "\\path to user folders\<%=Right(Request.ServerVariables("LOGON_USER"),6)%>\"
```